# Restrict json schema to Polygon from GeoJson

Tags: json, geojson, jsonschema

I'm building a JSON Schema which has a property `boundary`. I'm referencing the GeoJson schema which works fine. Now I want to restrict my boundary to be of type `Polygon`, which is an `enum` from the GeoJson schema.

How to do this?

This is the relevant part of my schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "plot": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "boundary": {
          "description": "The boundary of the plot",
          "title": "Plot boundary",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "required": [
            "type",
            "coordinates",
            "crs"
          ],
          "TODO": "Restrict to (multi)polygons only.",
          "$ref": "http://json.schemastore.org/geojson"
        }      
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my validating json:

```
{
  "plot":
  {
    "boundary": {
      "crs": {
        "type": "name",
        "properties": {
          "name": "EPSG:3857"
        }
      },
      "coordinates": [],
      "type": "MultiPolygon"
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: A note. The geojson schema you reference is in draft-4 while the schema you have is draft-7. The behaviour of referencing a schema of a different draft to your own is not defined.

Comment: So I should change my schema to draft-7 as well? I can do that, but how about my question to restrict to polygons only?

Comment: Your schema shows it is draft-7, but the geojson schema is draft-4. Rather than reference it, you should copy the bits that you want, and update them to draft-7 as required. Additionally you should not that you cannot use $ref alongside any other keys in an object in your schema. The other keys will be ignored. (This changes for draft-8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was using the wrong geojson.
I changed my code and now it works as expected and the new schemas are draft-7 as well.
Here's my updated code:

```
        "boundary": {
          "title": "The boundary of the plot",
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "$ref": "http://geojson.org/schema/MultiPolygon.json"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "http://geojson.org/schema/Polygon.json"
            }
          ],
          "additionalProperties": false
```

and

```
            "geoLocation": {
              "title": "Front door geolocation",
              "$ref": "http://geojson.org/schema/Point.json",
              "additionalProperties": false
            },
```

The JSON could be:

```
  "boundary":
  {
    "type": "Polygon",
    "coordinates": [
      [
        [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0], [100.0, 1.0],
        [100.0, 0.0]
      ]
    ]
  }
```

and

```
    "geoLocation": {
      "coordinates": [125.25, 135.255],
      "type": "Point"
    }
```